# Google Maps Geocoding Post Code 0821 in Australia Only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-geocoder

I am attempting to geocode an australian postcode 0821 and it does not reliably identify this postcode exists within the Northern Territory. 0820 and 0822 work fine.

example of what I'm doing

```
      var gm = google.maps;
      var gc = new gm.Geocoder();
      var grq:google.maps.GeocoderRequest = {
        address:s, region:"au"
      };
      var m = /[0-9]{4}/.exec(s);
      if(m && m.length == 1)
        grq.componentRestrictions = {
          country:'au'/*, postalCode:m[1]*/
        };
      gc.geocode(grq,(results, status)=>{
        if(status == gm.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
          $.ajax({
            url:`${apiUrl}near/${latLng.lat()},${latLng.lng()}`,
            success: (response)=>this.parseResult(response,latLng)});
        } else {
          this.search.searchEnded();
          console.warn("Gecode Failed",results,status);
          alert('Unable to find location, try entering more specific search');
        }
```

This example https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/geocoding-simple also seems to show similar problems, rather than not locating 0821, shows it in Buenos Aries (searching 'Australia 0821' or '0821 Australia'), searching 'Australia 0822' works find though.

I have also tried using postalCode restrictions, and that makes thing worse.

How do you reliably geocode a postcode?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'AU',
    postalCode: postcode
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer provides the clue to the solution but does not explain why the OP can not  "reliably geocode a postcode".
The reason is that GeoCode does not know whether the number given refers to a STREET NUMBER or a POSTCODE unless the filter shown by user3372176 is added to the request. Google looks for the street number first. Low numbered postcodes are more likely to match a street number and point to an address in WoopWoop

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the [AusPost's postcode api](https://developers.auspost.com.au/) if this is Australian specific, otherwise there are a number of API's (http://www.zippopotam.us/) being a good one imo.

This could simply be a bug in google's system, I'd probably report it in their product forum if all similar post codes are working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for two different postal codes (5000, 0800) in AU today and decided to use a fail-over approach and make two calls, instead of one.

Postal code 5000 would return results and 0800 wouldn't and vice versa using only singular methods, so I came up with this:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>

<script>
  var region = 'AU';
  var zip = '2000';
  var address = zip + ',' + region;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address,
    'componentRestrictions': {
      'country': region,
      'postalCode': zip
    }
  }, function(results, status) {
    //check status
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      //do work here 
    } else {
      console.log('STATUS - ', status);
      console.log('Trying with only component restrictions.');
      geocoder.geocode({
        'componentRestrictions': {
          'country': region,
          'postalCode': zip
        }
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          console.log("Works! - ", status);
        } else {
          console.log("noResults - ", status);
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Even this code seems to fail to geolocate 2000 as Sydney Australia.

Comment: I have discovered, however I cannot get 2018, 2017, & 2015 to map... I think I may need to include State in front of the zip.

Comment: I ended up using australia posts free location lookup for post codes